# How to identify what is not a Class?

Tags: language-agnostic, oop

I know the rule of thumb is that a noun used by the user is potentially a class. Similarly, a verb may be made into an action class e.g. predicate

Given a description from the user, how do you -

- identify what is not not to be made into a class

Answer (score 3):

The only real answer is experience. However, some things fairly obviously (to me, anyway) cannot be modelled in your design. For example if the use case says:

"and then the parcel is put on the UPS van"

There is no need to model the van. You can make decisions of this kind by considering the system boundaries - you don't and can't control the van.  However,

"we make a request to UPS for pickup"

might well result in a UPSPickup object.

Comment: You can create different object models. There`s no right one. And those that work are the right one. If your solution is working it still can be improved. So it`s really all about experience, that`s why people use design patterns (reusable abstractions and euristics of a good design parts) and refactoring(to see the smells and improve the current design).

Answer (score 0):

The rules are simple.

- Everything is an object.
- All objects belong to classes.

In rare (very rare circumstances) you have some specialized class/object confusion.

1. A "library" of all static methods.  This is an implementation choice, and no user can see this.
2. A **Singleton** where there can only be one object of the given class.  This does happen sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

In an OO language it is not a question of what to be made into a class, but rather 'what class does this data/functionality go into?'

Like other software architecture aspects there are rules, but ultimately it is an art that requires experience. There are lots of books on software design, but a simple reference is [Coupling and Cohesion](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?CouplingAndCohesion).

- Cohesion of a single module/component is the degree to which its responsibilities form a meaningful unit; higher cohesion is better.
- Coupling between modules/components is their degree of mutual interdependence; lower coupling is better.